# PostgreSQL - Optimize subquery by referencing outer query

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I have two tables: users and orders. Orders is a massive table (>100k entries) and users is relatively small (around 400 entries).

I want to find the number of orders per user. The column linking both tables is the email column.

I can achieve this with the following query:

```
SELECT sub_1.num, u.id FROM users AS u,
(SELECT cust_email AS email, COUNT(purchaseid) AS num
    FROM orders AS o
    WHERE o.status = 'COMPLETED'
    GROUP BY cust_email) sub_1
WHERE u.email = sub_1.email
ORDER BY createdate DESC NULLS LAST
```

However, as mentioned previously, the order table is very large, so I would ideally want to add another condition to the WHERE clause in the Subquery to only retrieve those emails that exist in the User table.

I can simply add the user table to the subquery like this:

```
 SELECT sub_1.num, u.id FROM users AS u,
(SELECT cust_email AS email, COUNT(purchaseid) AS num
    FROM orders AS o, users AS u
    WHERE o.status = 'COMPLETED'
    and o.cust_email = u.email
    GROUP BY cust_email) sub_1
WHERE u.email = sub_1.email
ORDER BY createdate DESC NULLS LAST
```

This does speed up the query, but sometimes the outer query is much more complex than just selecting all entries from the user table. Therefore, this solution does not always work. The goal would be to somehow link the outer and the inner query. I've thought of joint queries but cannot figure out how to get it to work.

I noticed that the first query seems to perform faster than I expected, so perhaps PostgreSQL is already smart enough to connect the outer and inner tables. However, I was hoping that someone could shed some light on how this works and what the best way to perform these types of subqueries is.

Comment: It is hard to guess what is going on without seeing the output from `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for the queries.

Comment: Your `order by` is suspect using a non existing column `createdate`. Also your query has close to no predicates (execpt for `status`), i.e. you'll have to *full scan* the tables and you **should not expect instant response** (This is the only advice you can get with the data you provided).

Comment: @MarmiteBomber The order by should not be relevant to the question at hand I believe, the goal is to optimize the subquery. We could simply remove the order by. And the question si precisely how to add a predicate from the outer query to the subquery. I only want to scan those rows in the "order" table in the subquery which email column appears in the outer query. Just as I show in the second query code example. But as I explain in the question this solution is not ideal for some cases and the question is therefore is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: The easiest is to not need checking at all. You can do this by making the `email` column unique in `users` and a FK in `orders`. Once that is done *it is guaranteed* the email exists in both tables.  An even better process however: Remove email from `orders` and replace it with`user.id`  then make the FK to `users`. Using email to link `orders` to `users`  is a poor choice - emails change after all. BTW for a modern database 100K rows is a very small table.